# Datepicker doesn't fit on layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Sorry for my poor English :) I have a layout and inside this layout has datepicker,textview etc. And if you look at the image, you can see the dates don't fit on the screen. After 20 or 21,22, vision isn't clear. How can I  change this?

I added xml layout codes:
http://codepaste.net/b6fgvu

[here is my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DVcn.png)

Comment: you should include the layout xml in your question.

Comment: I added.Thank you for your attention.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289731/are-we-actually-forbidden-from-linking-to-external-tools-such-as-codepen-jsfiddl